# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC : views are not mapped after adding Identity in project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, razor-pages, asp.net-core-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project working fine before adding identity. When I added scaffolded identity and injected the service in `program.cs`, the views are not mapped/displayed. If I route to the Razor pages of identity, it loads without any error. But when I route to any views, it shows the ERROR 404 message.

This is my `program.cs` file - please let me know if I am supposed to elaborate more. Thank you!

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(
    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
    ));

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
var app = builder.Build();
 
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();;

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{area=Customer}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

I tried updating the packages but to no avail. When I remove the following code, it again displays the views.

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

app.MapRazorPages();
```

Comment: You mean you remove"builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();" and it works fine? So what's your problem? Could you explain it clear?

Comment: Do you have an area name`Customer`? Is  the views are not mapped  in Customer area?

Comment: @QingGuo I have area name Customer and Admin

Comment: @QingGuo i mean that if i remove above mentioned three lines of code the mvc views are routed. but when i keep these three lines only the razor pages of identity are routed, no any other mvc pages are being routed/mapped

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

Try :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(
    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
    ));

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

var app = builder.Build();
 
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();;

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();
```

If you want to add  area , read[Areas for controllers with views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-6.0#areas-for-controllers-with-views) to know more.

Comment: I have area in my project (Admin and Customer), so, removing area in the code pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); did not work

Comment: @nepCoder I mean you can refer to [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-6.0#areas-for-controllers-with-views)  to set your area route. Besides, I use the above code and I can route both mvc view and  razor pages of identity .

Answer (score 1):

The order of middlewares matters (they are called in order of registration) and calling `app.MapRazorPages();` before routing and auth ones seems suspicious to me. Try moving it after, for example:

```cs
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{area=Customer}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();
```

Useful links:

- [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: reordering app.MapRazorPages(); did not work.